# Help me solve rebus puzzle in brackets ( = 2:15 pm )

Tags: rebus

[image: 2:15 pm]

I have figured out the 1st box which is basic: *I Understand*.

What is the answer to the second box, circled in yellow? I am not sure if the circled 25 & 31 are part of the puzzle or just the number of the puzzle.

Comment: Looks like the puzzle # to me

Comment: 31 is *scrambled egg*

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Or it could be a "bad egg" as in a rogue.

Comment: Is there an overarching theme to the page of rebuses?

Comment: It looks like you're asking us to solve a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content that you did not create yourself, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)** - at minimum you need to let us know where this came from, and any additional context you can provide is usually a big help to solvers. Posts which use someone else's content without disclosing where it came from are generally deleted.

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold until proper attribution of its original source is provided. You may add in attribution and request
 to have this post considered for reopening, if you wish.

Comment: Thats correct. It was posted in a facebook group. However there is no real importance on finding the answer. Was just very curious. So this post may be deleted if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

I think the one in yellow circle means.

> Equal Time

Comment: Why downvote? Tbh, this may be true.. Like a puzzle in here (search: "Once upon a time") http://www.billsgames.com/brainteasers/answer.cgi?show=-1

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> 30 degrees which is the angle that is created between the hour and minute hand at 2:15